# How to integrate OpenCV with Ionic 3?

Tags: android, opencv, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I am building a mobile app for body measurement through photo I capture. how I can use OpenCV for the same? How to integrate OpenCV with Ionic framework? Kindly help.

Comment: Are you trying to incorporate OpenCV.js or a non-JS flavor?

Comment: Hi @BRass OpenCV.js

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you can pull in a flavor of the opencv.js framework.  The way I've done it is by pulling down some reference like `https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/opencv.js`, and then hosting it somewhere (in case opencv moves it on you).  Then include that script in the Ionic project.  Be careful how you do that though.  It is a big file, so it could take the app longer to load.  Some options I've used:

**Local Asset**

Store the js file in the local assets, and include it in the index.js.  If the Ionic app is deployed as a native app, then this asset is already in the app and fairly fast to load.

```
<script src="assets/js/opencv.js" async></script>
```

**Dynamically load the file (example below)**

```
async ionViewDidLoad() {

    let loadingScreen = this.loadingCtrl.create({ content: "Loading Scripts. Please Wait..." });

    //Show loading screen & load scripts
    try {
      await loadingScreen.present();
      await this.loadScript();
    }
    catch (error) {
      this.errorMessage = "We had some trouble loading scripts...";
    }
    finally {
      loadingScreen && loadingScreen.dismiss();
    }
}


public loadScript(): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var isFound = false;
      var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script")
      for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; ++i) {
        if (scripts[i].getAttribute('src') != null && 
scripts[i].getAttribute('src').includes("opencv")) {
          isFound = true;
          return resolve();
        }
      }

      if (!isFound) {
        var dynamicScripts = ["https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/opencv.js"];

        for (var i = 0; i < dynamicScripts.length; i++) {
          let scriptNode = document.createElement('script');
          scriptNode.src = dynamicScripts[i];
          scriptNode.type = 'text/javascript';
          scriptNode.async = false;
          scriptNode.charset = 'utf-8';
          document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(scriptNode);

          scriptNode.onload = resolve;
        }
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @BRass for your kind reply, I will check it and update you.

Comment: @Sandesh Did you try on this? Even I am working on a similar project, just wanted to check if you were able to use the JS flavor of OpenCV with your Ionic app. Although I am trying on Ionic 4.